How do I export a custom view from Yahoo finance
I created a Yahoo Finance portfolio and added a view with the fields I want.  When I select that portfolio and select that view I see the fields I want.  If I then push the export button I get the portfolio with a subset of the "basic" view rather than the fields I selected.
What do I have to do to export a portfolio with fields of my choosing?
Here's a view of my custom view...

And here's what I get from th export...

What I really care about is some way for me to select the fields that are exported.  I don't really care if that selection is tied to a particular view or not.  I'd be happy if there was all kinds of extraneous stuff I didn't want in the export as long as I got the stuff I wanted.
It would also be useful if I knew this was impossible; at least I'd stop beating a dead horse. ;-)

I found the same question on redit from 5 yrs ago without an answer. https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/e7v7uo/yahoo_finance_portfolio_export_or_other/?rdt=37890

This can be done with a cut and paste to some extent.
At least using Firefox you get a tab separated text file using a plain text paste.   That can be imported into a spreadsheet with only a little clean up.  I paste this into Libre Office Calc and then clean up the data.   There seems to be a tab generated after the symbol name but other fields are correctly aligned.
I'd prefer a CSV export but this works better than typing.
